# git cherry pick and hightlight all changes with (conflict) markers

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I want to add changes from a specific commit using `git cherry-pick commitId`.

**However, it would be very useful to mark all changes** (for example with conflict markers) so I can accept them manually.

As a novice I failed to find a solution online. I stumbled upon `-no-ff` option, hoping this does not automatically make changes, but it did.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: A `git diff @`  is not good enough? IDEs also provide the support to compare against `@`  (a.k.a. `HEAD`) so you can do that very comfortably.

Comment: `git diff` is the second best approach, but it would be more convenient to have it inline

Comment: What do you mean _"second best"_? The fact that it's not available means it's not like people are _begging_ for it. As a punchline: `git diff` and comparing with IDEs would be best approach.... what you want to do would be `[-1]` in python indexing. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a "slowed down" cherry-pick and review each change individually, you can use the `--no-commit` flag (or `-n` in short form) and use interactive add:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commitId>

# at this point, all changes are present but nothing commited yet

git reset
git add -p
```

It will then cycle through each chunk of change (even non-conflicts), for you to decide what you need (take, leave, edit, etc.)

(You *could* also, instead of resetting/re-adding at the end, just `git reset -p` and interactively *unstage* changes you don't want, but the logic might feel a bit backwards for some people, feel free to use it if you prefer)

Comment: this does not mark the changes in the file itself, but allows convenient iteration through all (potential) changes. Thanks!